# How do i keep my loop from repeating my random values?

Tags: python, numpy, random, probability, dice

So i was learning how to handle probabilities and how to plot them in Python. I came across a problem where i needed to find the probability of the sum of 2 dices being > 7 or odd. I know the result is around 75% but it was translating that to Python that i had a problem with. My code to solve the problem is something like this:

```
import random
import numpy as np
dice = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
value = 0
simulation_number = len(dice)**2
percentage = []
for i in range(0,simulation_number):
    dice1 = random.choice(dice)
    dice2 = random.choice(dice)
    random_match = dice1,dice2
    
    if (sum(random_match))>7 or (sum(random_match)%2) != 0:
        value += 1
percentage.append(np.round((value/simulation_number)*100,2))
print(percentage,"%")
```

It works just fine but everytime i run the code it gives a different solution because the loop is repeating outcomes for random_match. How do I include in the code the condition of not repeating random_match values?

Comment: what do you mean by repeating outcomes for random_match? it is different because you did not set seed? (i.e. np.random.seed)

Comment: simply run your code in def and call in with previous random matchs

Comment: The code seems okay to me... you are getting a different solution every time because of sampling error…  try cranking the simulation_number up to one million or more and you should get a lot closer to 75%

Comment: If each iteration of the loop is supposed to represent a separate dice toss then repetition must be allowed as that is a natural possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating random values from 1 to 6 won't work. Assume that you are tossing a coin 10 times. theoretically you should get 5 heads and 5 tails. But that does not happens in real life because of sampling error. When you generate random values, there is always some sampling error.

```
import random
import numpy as np
dice = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
value = 0
simulation_number = len(dice)**2
for i in range(len(dice)):
    for j in range(len(dice)):
        dice1 = dice[i]
        dice2 = dice[j]
        x = dice1+dice2
        if x>7 or x%2== 1:
            value += 1
percentage = np.round((value/simulation_number)*100,2)
print(f'{percentage} %')
```

This works as you need every case only once. Using random might take same case again and again

Comment: This will give you the correct answer of 75% but is more of a calculation than a simulation.

Comment: Yeah but if you want to run simulation, the iterations should be theoretically infinite

Comment: Yes, in theory the result would infinitely approach 75% but never reach it exactly.. I can do 10 million iterations on my laptop in a few seconds and I get 74.99%

Comment: @Binbougami if you want a calculation then this answer is the correct approach.. otherwise your code is fine but you might want to increase the simulation_number.

Comment: @JacobPhilpott also it was not specified that he wanted to run a simulation. I gave him reason why is that happening and also the correct way to do it. I deserve an upvote

Comment: Tossing a coin 10 times can give you anything from 0 to 10 heads.  That's just as true in theory as in reality.  Theory tells us that the **average** number of heads will be 5 - but that's for many such tosses.  But that's the core of the issue - theory can give us the probability distribution, simulation approximates it with a sampling distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for `random.sample`:

```
import random
dice = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
dice1, dice2 = random.sample(dice, 2)
```

Comment: This is flawed, if you are rolling two separate dice they can ofcourse land on the same number!